# getting hibernate default schema name programmatically from session factory?

Tags: hibernate, sessionfactory

I was wondering if there is a way to get the default schema name from session factory, somehow? The reason I need to get it is because I have to use a one native SQL and I have multiple session factories for multiple schemas and a single data source. All the generated hibernate queries are being ran by a single user which has select access to other schemas.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I just found out that hibernate has {h-schema} replacement that can be used in native sql queries. So this does the job cleanly when you are connected to a one schema in oracle database and want to execute queries against different schemas. Example would be:

```
select * from {h-schema}table_name
```

This ways instead of doing a manual `replaceAll` in a query, hibernate will take care of everything given that each session factory is configured with `"hibernate.default_schema"` property.

Comment: I had problems when using Restrictions.sqlRestriction(...)

Answer (score 8):

I had problems with John's solution to use {h-schema} when using the Criteria api's Restrictions.sqlRestriction(...) (probably because this substitution happens within the separate HQL api). Similar to Michael's solution, I used:

```
SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor)sessionFactory;
String name = sfi.getSettings().getDefaultSchemaName();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick:

```
  SessionFactoryImplementor sfi = (SessionFactoryImplementor) getSessionFactory();           
  Settings settings = sfi.getSettings();
  ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = settings.getConnectionProvider();
  try {
        Connection connection = connectionProvider.getConnection();
        DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData = connection.getMetaData();
        String url = databaseMetaData.getURL();
        //substring the string to what you want
        System.out.println(url);
  } catch (SQLException e) {
       //throw something
  }
```

Comment: On my system, this does reply the connection url... not the schema.

Answer (score 0):

@Ryan Morlok, I can not comment on your answer due to lack of reputation. Your answer is correct, but its deprecated now. In hibernate version 5.0.1, schema name can be get using

```
(SessionFactoryImpl)sessionFactory).getProperties().getProperty("hibernate.default_schema")
```