# Manage @NamedNativeQuery and schema

Tags: jpa, schema, nativequery

I have many `EntityManager`, one per schema that I have (I use `entity-mappings` file to map EMs with schemas). It works.

When I use `@NamedQuery` it's working like a charm but when I use `@NamedNativeQuery` schema is not used. I have to qualify with it `SELECT foo FROM schema.table`.

Is it the right behaviour ?

I think it's not possible to parameter `@NamedNativeQuery` to dynamically pass schema (I believe only columns can be dynamics not tables or schemas or anything else) so how can I use `@NamedNativeQuery` with dynamic schema please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excerpts from documentation :

- **NamedNativeQuery :** Specifies a named native SQL query. Query names are scoped to the persistence unit.
- **NamedQuery :** Specifies a static, named query in the Java Persistence    query language. Query names are scoped to the persistence unit.

It isn't specified directly that `NamedNativeQuery` is static, but both are same scoped & can't be altered afterwards & it's the desired behaviour.

Named queries are mean to be accessed by multiple modules - application wide, identified by unique name, so they are static & constant. You can try building a query string dynamically & can create a native query from it, instead of named native query.

Comment: I know I can do that. So for you, it is impossible to use named native query with dynamic schema ? Ty

Comment: @OlivierJ. Yes, can't pass table/schema etc. as parameter to named query

Comment: ok I will generate my query with string dynamically. Thank you

Comment: Generating any query strings dynamically can pose a security risk if the values are taken from unmanaged sources like user-input so this should be done with care. Additionally, dynamic queries cannot take advantage of the connection-pool management performance features for query and execution-plan reuse within the database. Would instead use logic to look up namedQueryX versus namedQueryY based on whatever conditions, with each NamedQuery bound to their respective persistence-units.

Comment: @DarrellTeague Yes, there is security risk if providing inputs directly into query instead of setting parameters/using named queries. It's preferred to have separate persistence unit.

Answer (score 8):

Prefix your table name with "{h-schema}", e.g.`SELECT foo FROM {h-schema}table`

(courtesy of [getting hibernate default schema name programmatically from session factory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832579/getting-hibernate-default-schema-name-programmatically-from-session-factory))

Comment: That's a nice one. And the schema name already includes the dot "."  XDD